# How to understand this integral result?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, expectation

I was reading this page on Wikipedia: 
[Birthday Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)

I can understand up until how to approximate the minimal number of attempts for a given probability  $$n(p; H) \approx \sqrt{2H \log \frac 1{1-p}}$$

Later on the page gave an expected value of number of attempts as $$Q(H) \approx \sqrt{\frac \pi 2H}$$

I think this is probably an integral over the first result times the probability. Can anybody give a few steps how to deduce the second result from the first result? I could not get the second result by myself.

Comment: Try to give a brief summary of the quantities involved, if we're talking about continuos or discrete random variables, what do you think the integral that defines $Q$ in terms of $n$ is and ideally also how you tried to solve it. Also, try to use LaTeX next time instead of posting images with the relevant math :-) Look here for how to do that: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of attempts without a collision. Then, we have

$\mathbb{E}[X]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}k\Pr[X = k]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{k}\Pr[X = k]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = n}^{\infty}\Pr[X = k]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Pr[X \ge n]$.

The probability that $X \ge n$ is simply the probability of having no collisions in $n$ attempts, which is the complement of the probability having a collision in $n$ attempts. Thus, $\Pr[X \ge n] = 1-p(n;H) \approx e^{-\tfrac{n^2}{2H}}$. (This approximation is given in the Wikipedia article in the equation immediately before the first equation in your question).

So, the expected number of attempts without a collision is approximately

$\mathbb{E}[X] = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Pr[X \ge n] = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}[1-p(n;H)] \approx \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}e^{-\tfrac{n^2}{2H}} \approx \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2H}}\,dx = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}H}$.

Comment: I got a question. You put Pr[X>=n] = 1- p(n;H). Pr[X>=n] sounds like the probability making more than n attempts and there are no collisions. The wiki page says 1 - p(n;H) means the probability making n attempts and there are more than 1 collisions. Do these two mean the same? Why?

Comment: The wiki page says "From a set of H values we choose n values uniformly at random thereby allowing repetitions. Let $p(n; H)$ be the probability that during this experiment at least one value is chosen more than once." So $p(n;H)$ is the probability of at least one collision with $n$ attempts. The complement $1-p(n;H)$ is the probability of no collisions with $n$ attempts.

Comment: Thanks that explained part of my confusion. The other part of my confusion is, you said the complement 1−p(n;H) is the probability of no collisions with n attempts. It sounds like Pr[X==n] = 1-p(n;H), but in your equation, you implied Pr[X>=n] = 1-p(n;H). It sounds like 1-p(n;H) really sums up not only Pr[X==n], but also Pr[X==n+1], Pr[X==n+2], etc. Why?

Comment: If the first $n$ attempts don't have a collision, then the number of attempts before the first collision could be $n$, or it could be $n+1$ or $n+2$ or any number greater than or equal to $n$. That's why $1-p(n;H) = \Pr[X=n]+\Pr[X=n+1]+\Pr[X=n+2]+\cdots = \Pr[X \ge n]$.

Comment: I understood now. The way you do $ \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}k\Pr[X = k] = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{k}\Pr[X = k]$ looks impressive. For the way you introduce a new variable and a new sum over this variable, is there a name/wiki page to it? Or is it a unique method to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, the calculation of the expected number of attempts before the first repeated value is a completely different problem than the number of attempts needed for the probability of a hit is some given $\rho$.

The sum you are doing in the expected value problem is

$$1 + \frac{1}{H} + 2 \frac{H-1}{H} \frac{2}{H} + 3 \frac{H-1}{H} \frac{H-2}{H} \frac{3}{H} + \cdots$$

This is $$1+\sum_{n=1}^H n^2 \frac{(H-1)!}{H^n (H-n)!}$$

The trick to this is to use Stirling's approximation for the factorials, ending up with a geometric series plus lower-order terms.  The miracle is that in the highest order term, the constant $e$ has disappeared (but the $\pi$ in Stirling's approximation has stuck around.

The next order term in the approximation for the expected value is not at all easy to get right.